# Accessing static non monobehaviour class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to access a static class from a mono-behaviour script. I am declaring the class with an instance but I get the error `Cannot declare a variable of static type 'MeshExtension'`. Even though creating an instance of the static class should work right? What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class MeshVolume : MonoBehaviour {
 public MeshExtension meshExt  = new MeshExtension();
 public Mesh mesh;
 public GameObject point;

void Start()
{
  if (MeshExtension.IsPointInside(mesh.InverseTransformPoint(point.transform)))
   {
   
   }
}

}
```

```
public static class MeshExtension
 {
     public static bool IsPointInside(this Mesh aMesh, Vector3 aLocalPoint)
     {
       //..
     }
 }
```

Comment: The whole point of a static class is that it does not need to be instantiated; you access their members via the type not a specific instance.

Comment: No, `static` classes cannot be instantiated. Access your method directly through the class: `MeshExtension.IsPointInside()`.

Comment: @dymanoid Thank you. But infact I tried to access it directly. It throws errors. I have updated my code.Am I doing it right? " 'Mesh' does not contain a definition for 'InverseTransformPoint' and no accessible extension method 'InverseTransformPoint' accepting a first argument of type 'Mesh' could be found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before there are multiple issues:

1. Your class is a [`static class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) with only `static` members. You can not create an instance of it like you did in

   ```
   public MeshExtension meshExt  = new MeshExtension();
   ```

   you would rather access the `static` members directly via the type itself using e.g.

   ```
   // Note that if you do it this way you have to pass in both parameters!
   MeshExtension.IsPointInside(someMesh, someVector);
   ```
2. However, this is an [**Extension Method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) as you can see on the **`this`** in `this Mesh aMesh`. Extension methods are treated in a special way: You can call them like if they were part of the type instance defined by `this` .. in your case a `Mesh` so you can simply call

   ```
   mesh.IsPointInside(someVector)
   ```
3. Finally [`Transform.InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) is not part of the `Mesh` but of `Transform`!

   So just assuming that the mesh here belongs to the object your script is attached to you would rather call e.g.

   ```
   if (mesh.IsPointInside(transform.InverseTransformPoint(point.transform)))
   ```

   where you would have to exchange the first `transform` in case you need the point relative to some other `Transform` component. Note that a `Mesh` itself has no clue by which object(s) it is used so you might need a second `public Transform meshOwner;` field in order to get the correct `InverseTransformPoint`.

Actually in case this mesh **is** on the same object I would rather retrieve it directly from the attached `MeshFilter` component like e.g.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class MeshVolume : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private MeshFilter _meshFilter;
    public GameObject point;
    private Mesh mesh;
 
    void Start()
    {
        if(!_meshFilter) _meshFilter= GetComponent<MeshFilter >();

        mesh = _meshFilter.mesh;

        mesh.IsPointInside(transform.InverseTransformPoint(point.transform.position)))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain this. Much appreciated!